# Eloquent save() not working after switching from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have just converted all tables of MySQL database from MyISAM to InnoDB by issue following:

```
ALTER TABLE month_fees ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Following code was working fine before converting table engine to InnoDB:

```
$m = MonthFee::where('id', Input::get('h_mf_id'))->first();
$m->deposit_date = $data['depositDate'];
$m->deposit_amount += $data['depositAmount'];
$m->relaxation += $data['relaxation'];
if($m->save()){
    Log::info('saved'.$m->deposit_date.'amount='.$m->deposit_amount);
}
```

But now, it is not updating table in database. Apparently, Eloquent/Laravel gives no error. As you can see on success of save() I logged some variables, Even these values are logged in Log file.

When I only changes table engine back to MyISAM, everything starts working fine.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Log your queries using http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#query-logging, and see if you can execute the `update` query correctly on mysql shell or phpMyAdmin. Maybe problem is not changing engine, but something else that happened at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

use **find()** method instead of **where()** like this

```
$m = MonthFee::find(Input::get('h_mf_id'));
$m->deposit_date = $data['depositDate'];
$m->deposit_amount += $data['depositAmount'];
$m->relaxation += $data['relaxation'];
if($m->save()){
    Log::info('saved'.$m->deposit_date.'amount='.$m->deposit_amount);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tested it with find() too, but no luck

Comment: Yes, If var_dump($m). I can see that it is extracting rows from database. Model is extracting data absolutely fine, the only issue is with save()